# Debugging IOS ... nothing shows in console

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a final project for school, forgive me, I am having difficulty so I am trying to run in debug ... what am I doing wrong? I set my breakpoints and I run the simulator, for some reason the simulator starts up but my project closes ... I reopen it and it is obviously running, but there is nothing present in the console, even when run the code that should break on. Please help if you can, I am really getting frustrated because I can't get my code to work and now I cannot get my debug to work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you see anything at all in the output section of the debug area when the application is running. Also have you changed any of the compiler options? Lastly the code you believe is breaking the application can you post this.

Comment: Oh and a bit of advice. I find it best to sometimes get up and walk away when things like this happen. Sometimes taking a short break is more beneficial than wrangling with something. Things are much clearer when you are not fully consciously thinking about something. I have spent hours trying to sort something before only to find while taking a break I realise how silly the issue was and ended up being solved within minutes.

Comment: Hi Peter ... I agree with the walking away part, I do that a lot. Thanks... here is the code I am having trouble with. it is not executing.

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:AcctName.text];
    [array addObject:AcctNum.text];
    [array addObject:DayDue.text];
    [array addObject:paymnt.text];
    [array addObject:remBalance.text];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"];
    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: true];

Comment: also as far the debugging... it is doing something, console shows blank... I accidentally typed some characters in the window. it shows "lldb" but that is it. and if I pause, it shows the registers, and when I start up again it runs through the registers, but does not show any output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

To see output in the "All Output" pane of the debugger, you need to call NSLog with a log string (which can be a format string with variables like printf).  If you do not have any NSLog calls, then you should not expect to see any output in the debugger.